# Headers in Angular HTTP Request to NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, angular, token

I can't send the headers in my HTTPs requests using my Angular app. I have to send a Token to authorize the request in my back-end that is a NodeJS API. Each route is checked.

When I print the request headers:

```
host: 'localhost:21124',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36',
'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization,content-type',
accept: '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'pt,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' }
```

I use the "Authorization" control header to send my Token.

Here is my CORS and the valitation (**API**):

```
app.use(helmet());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.url !== '/login') {
        var token = req.headers['Authorization'];
        if (!token) {
            res.status(401).send('Token não provido!')
        } else {
            jwt.verify(token, SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send('Token inválido!');
            } else if (decoded) {
                var date = new Date();
            if (decoded.exp < date.getTime()) {
                next();
            } else {
                res.status(500).send('Token inválido!');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Here is my Angular API Service where I do the requests (one request for example):

```
getAssociados(idClube: string): any {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token });
   const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   return this.http.get(this.associadoUrl + idClube, options)
      .map(res => res.json());
```

}

I already used Postman to do the resquests. Everything fine. I got the error just in my Angular app (No authorized).

Comment: When making the request in angular, is it sending the `Authorization` header? Also, can you confirm that token is not `null`.

Comment: Have you hosted your angular app?

Comment: @dzm I think Angular is not sending, but I added the Authorization to the header. Yes, the token is not null.

Comment: @Java Yes, I do. I build and deploy the Angular app as well the API. Same error.

Comment: Is it possible to post the specific changes you made to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [discussion of cross-origin](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html), if you send

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

then no authorization information is ever sent.  You will need to change your node.js app to send an `access-control-allow-origin` header that explicitly mentions the `origin` header you get.

In addition, note that the `options` preflight request will not include the `authorization` header; that is only sent after the browser validates the cross-origin request.

Comment: Is it possible in localhost? I got the same error using http://localhost:4200. No Authorization field in header recived.

Comment: Error 01: `OPTIONS http://localhost:21124/associado/5a030b4e9f90381a3d486204 401 (Unauthorized)`; Error 02: `Failed to load http://localhost:21124/associado/5a030b4e9f90381a3d486204: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401`

Comment: You need to get the preflight options request to return 200 with  the right headers as discussed in the answer.

Comment: Solved. Thanks, but I have to do more changes: `var token = req.headers['authorization'].replace(/"/g, '');` the Authorization must be in low case and I alse have to remove the quoute marks.